# Cannot declare a class instance to be assigned to as an out parameter of library function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, out, out-parameters

My VB.NET script needs to use a library written in C#, specifically the `Connect()` method that has an `out` parameter that is a class.
The VB.NET code calling the library method looks like this:

```
Dim devInfo As DeviceInfoType
myDevice.Connect(ChannelType.DEV_CHANNEL, 0, devInfo)
```

How the declaration looks like in the C# library:

```
// `ChannelType` is just an enum.
void Connect(ChannelType channel, UInt16 connectMode, out DeviceInfoType devInfo);

public class DeviceInfoType
{
    public GetIdType GetId { get; set; }
}
```

When I call `myDevice.Connect()` the computer waits a few seconds then an error is thrown (so I assume the device is being connected to, and once a connection is made the method tries to assign device info to the `out` parameter):

```
Object not set to instance of object
```

I can call other methods of `myDevice` just fine, so I assume it's something to do with the `DeviceInfoType` parameter.
The author of the C# library told me that a C# user would have to call `Connect()` like this, but of course there is no `out` keywoard in VB.NET:

```
myDevice.Connect(ChannelType.DEV_CHANNEL, 0x00, out devInfo);
```

I also tried declaring `devInfo` like this, but still get the same error:

```
Dim devInfo As DeviceInfoType = Nothing
Dim devInfo As New DeviceInfoType
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws that exception? Did you step through the code and found out which object is referred to by the error message? As you suggested, VB doesn't have an equivalent to the `out` keyword; it's not needed. If `myDevice.Connect(ChannelType.DEV_CHANNEL, 0x00, out devInfo);` works in a C# project, then `Dim devInfo As DeviceInfoType = Nothing : myDevice.Connect(ChannelType.DEV_CHANNEL, 0, devInfo)` should also work just fine in a VB project. If not, then there's probably something else going on that is not present in the question.

Comment: I would start by confirming that the `Connect()` method actually works when called in a C# assembly and then try to identify which object is `null` in VB when the exception occurs. That's, of course, assuming that it does work in C#.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thank you for the suggestion. `myDevice.Connect()` is the line where the exception is thrown, I step until this function but of course cannot go inside it. After this call execution jumps to my `finally` block and then the error is shown. Before `Connect()` is called, `devInfo`'s value is `{Nothing}`. I may have to try using the library call in C#, maybe something is wrong with it?

Comment: That's very likely. Based on the information you provided so far, nothing prevents the method to be called from VB if it works in C#. Here's a [quick example](https://i.imgur.com/ZNItJdO.png) which shows a close-enough C# method being called in a VB project.

Comment: What does the exception's stack trace tell you?

Comment: All `TryParse` methods (for example) are declared like this. If you have an exception, read what the exception is. *the computer waits a few seconds then an error is thrown (so I assume the device is being connected to...)*. I'ld assume the opposite.

Comment: `out` is a C# feature rather than something defined in MSIL.  It means that an additional attribute is placed on the argument (which you can also do in VB although in VB it doesn't have syntactic meaning), and the language enforces a requirement to set the value of the argument within the body of the routine.  From the perspective of any other language, it's just another `ref` argument (or `ByRef` if you prefer).

Comment: VB should interoperate just fine with `out` arguments.  Do beware that as with any `ByRef` argument, under certain circumstances it will pass by copy-in/copy-out instead of directly by reference i.e. changes occurring within the routine won't be visible by any other route (e.g. any sort of aliasing) until the routine ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the library function that was doing something that caused the `Object not set to instance of object` exception. It happens because the `0x00` argument is not in the valid range; once I passed a value in the valid range there were no problems.